# Get list of values of different child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to obtain the values ​to show them in a recyclerview, I have tried in many ways but without fortune.

This is my firebase data.

```
"Users" : {

    "X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2" : {
      "images" : {
        "urlImages1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg1.jpg?alt=media&token=e26fd6a2-2be7-4a01-920e-0aed1fe06436",
        "urlImages2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg2.jpg?alt=media&token=40165918-3b46-4b22-b0ef-255965b7855d",
        "urlImages3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg3.jpg?alt=media&token=cfd7d00d-9b1a-44fd-80d4-a2947f7de743",
        "urlImages4" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg4.jpg?alt=media&token=995419a7-70f7-4330-b046-d06a4d54453e",
        "urlImages6" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg6.jpg?alt=media&token=ee6f566a-a9e5-4e8f-9d53-64d3f3bc97a6",
        "urlImages7" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg7.jpg?alt=media&token=883a3321-fbba-49bd-aae3-14b005b4cc5b"
      },
      "locations" : {
        "locations1" : "14.2830817 -89.7263953",
        "locations2" : "14.2661424 -89.7220017",
        "locations3" : "14.2846352 -89.7251991",
        "locations4" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
        "locations5" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
        "locations6" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
        "locations7" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704"
      }
```

I want to get the data from "images" and "locations".

```
    imageRef = database.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);


    imageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


             for (DataSnapshot mData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                 String mImages = mData.child("images").getValue(String.class);
                 String mLocations  =  mData.child("locations").getValue(String.class);


                    ItemData itemData = new ItemData();
                    itemData.setImages(mImages);
                    itemData.setLocations(mLocations);

                    data.add(itemData);

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

What I try to do is show the image and the location in a recyclerview. The "images" key contains url1, url2, url3... in the same way the "locations" key and I want to show them together in the adapter.

Please look at the image of the link

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use this code to get the data from `images`:

```
String mImages = mData.child("images").getValue(String.class);
```

But if we look at your JSON, the `images` property looks like this:

```
  "images" : {
    "urlImages1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg1.jpg?alt=media&token=e26fd6a2-2be7-4a01-920e-0aed1fe06436",
    "urlImages2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg2.jpg?alt=media&token=40165918-3b46-4b22-b0ef-255965b7855d",
    "urlImages3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg3.jpg?alt=media&token=cfd7d00d-9b1a-44fd-80d4-a2947f7de743",
    "urlImages4" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg4.jpg?alt=media&token=995419a7-70f7-4330-b046-d06a4d54453e",
    "urlImages6" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg6.jpg?alt=media&token=ee6f566a-a9e5-4e8f-9d53-64d3f3bc97a6",
    "urlImages7" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg7.jpg?alt=media&token=883a3321-fbba-49bd-aae3-14b005b4cc5b"
  },
```

That is an entire JSON object, not merely a string. So you call will return `null`, since the value is not a string.

To get all image URLs from this JSON, you will need to loop over its child nodes and get the individual values from there:

```
for (DataSnapshot imageSnapshot: mData.child("images").getChildren()) {
  System.out.println(imageSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
}
```

Since there can be (and are) multiple images and locations, *either* your `ItemData` will need to handle those, *or* you will need to select a single image and location, *or* you will have to convert all images/locations into a single string.